# Difference Between C and C++ Executables?

Tags: c++, c, executable, binaries

I know there are differences in the source code between C and C++ programs - this is **not** what I'm asking about.

I also know this will vary from CPU to CPU and OS to OS, depending on compiler.

I'm teaching myself C++ and I've seen numerous references to libraries that can be used by both languages.  This has started me thinking - are there significant differences between the binary executables of the two languages?

For libraries to be easily used by both, I would think they'd have to be similar on an executable level.

Are there many situations where a person could examine a executable file and tell whether it was created by C or C++ source code?  Or would the binaries be pretty similar?

Comment: What you really want to ask is how functions (and more generally *symbols*) are exported by compilers of either language...

Comment: @Tango: There's no real difference between the binaries; they're both native code, stored in the same format.

Comment: The executable doesn't really have anything to do with the language that was used to create it. If you had two programs, one in C and the other in C++, that both did exactly the same thing, there's no reason their executables couldn't be exactly the same. However, compilers tend to leave things behind that make an executable identifiable as having been written in a certain language - but that's not at all necessary.

Comment: Generally, these folks are correct. However, neither C nor C++ need to be compiled; They may very well be interpreted, instead. Interpretation is just another method of translation which translates to behaviour, rather than to another programming language.

Comment: What you are looking for is the **ABI**. A quick google will show you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In most cases, yes, it's pretty easy. Here are just a few clues that I've seen often enough to remember them easily:

1. C++ program will typically end up with at least a few visible symbols that have been mangled.
2. C++ program will typically have at least a *few* calls to virtual functions, which are typically quite distinctive from code you'll typically see in C.
3. Many C++ compilers implement a calling convention for C++ that gives special consideration to passing the `this` pointer into C++ member functions. Again, since the `this` pointer simply doesn't exist in C, you'll rarely see a direct analog (though in some cases, they will use the same convention to pass some other pointer, so you need to be careful about this one).

Answer (score 4):

A executable is a executable is a executable, no matter what language it's written in.  If it's built for the target architecture, it'll run on the architecture.

The (arguably) most important difference between C and C++-compiled code, and the one relevant to libraries that can be *linked* both against C and C++ executables, is that of [name mangling.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)  Basically: when a library is compiled, it exports a set of symbols (function names, exported variables, etc.) that executables linked against the library can use.  How these symbols are *named* is a fairly compiler/linker-specific, and if the subsequent executable is linked using a linker using an incompatible convention, then symbols won't resolve correctly.  In addition, C and C++ have slightly different conventions.  The Wikipedia article linked above has more of the details; suffice to say, when declaring exported symbols in a header file, you'll usually see a construction like:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* exported declarations here */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

`__cplusplus` is a preprocessor macro only defined when compiling C++ code.  The idea here is that, when using the header in C++, the compiler is instructed to use the C way of naming exported symbols (inside the "`extern "C" { /* foo */ }`" block, so the library can be linked both in C and C++ correctly.

Comment: Also, tango is not a ballroom dance! :-P

Answer (score 2):

I *think* I could tell if something is C++ or C from reading the disassembled binary code [for processor architectures that I'm familiar with, x86, x86_64 and ARM]. But in reality, there isn't much difference, you'd have to look pretty hard to know for sure.

Signs to look for are "indirect calls" (`function pointer calls via a table`) and `this`-pointers. Although C can have `pointer to struct` arguments and will often use function pointers, it's not usually set up in the way that C++ does it. Also, you'll notice, sometimes, that the compiler takes a pointer to a struct and adds a small offset - that's removing the outer layer of an inherited class. This CAN happen in C as well, but it won't be as common/distinctive.

Looking just at the binary [unless you can "do disassembly in your head" would be a lot harder - especially if it's been stripped of symbols - that's like the guy who could tell you what classical music something was on an old Vinyl record from looking at the tracks [with the label hidden] - not something most people can do, even if they are "good".

Answer (score 1):

In practice, a C program (or a C++ program) is rarely only pure standard C (or C++) (for instance the C99 standard has no mean to scan a directory). So programs use additional libraries.

On Linux, most binaries are dynamically linked. Use the `ldd` command to find out.

If the binary is linked to the `stdc++` library, the source code is likely C++.

If only the `libc.so` library is linked, the source code is probably only C (but you could link statically the `libstdc++.a` library).

You can also use tools working on binary files (e.g. `objdump`, `readelf`, `strings`, `nm` on Linux ....) to find more about them.

Answer (score 1):

The code generated by C and C++ compilers is generally the same code. There are two important differences:

- Name mangling: Each function and global variable becomes a *symbol* at compile time. In C these symbol's names are the same as their names in your source code. In C++ they are being mangled a bit to allow for polymorphic code
- Calling conventions: If you call a method in C++ the this-pointer is passed as a hidden first parameter. Other conventions might also be different such as call by reference which does not exist in C

You can use an block such as this to let the C++-compiler generate code compatible to C:

```
extern "C" {
    /* code */
}
```